# Change the height of my element dynamically based on current window aspect ratio

Tags: css, sass

I want to add a bottom: value to my div where the value will vary be based on the browser window aspect ratio.

Is there a  way to get the current aspect ratio width /height of my browser window in CSS?

```
.loading-animation{
bottom: ?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `vh, vw` viewport-height and viewport-width respectively. The content will adjust itself depending on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [aspect-radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property in CSS.

That property auto size the elements in reference about you screen size.